# Print certain part of a restatable theorem only the first time

Tags: thmtools, restatable

I am in the standard scenario for restatable: I am using restatable to state a lemma in the short version of the paper, whose proof is given in the appendix. In the appendix, I want to restate the lemma before giving its proof.

Now here is the catch. I want to use $\spadesuit$ to denote a lemma (in the short version) whose proof is in the appendix. But, I want $\spadesuit$ to only show up in the short version, and not the second time when the statement is printed in the appendix. How do I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,thm-restate,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{restatable}{lemma}{mylemma}[$\spadesuit$] \label{lem:mylemm}
$1+1=2$
\end{restatable}
\appendix
\mylemma*
\begin{proof}
We know that $2-1 = 1$, which shows the lemma.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a command instead of the explicit tokens; you can redefine the command at `\appendix` so it produces nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,thm-restate,amssymb}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newcommand{\restatemarker}{\textup{[$\spadesuit$]} \ignorespaces}
\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}{\renewcommand{\restatemarker}{}}

\begin{document}

\section{Main}

\begin{restatable}{lemma}{mylemma}\label{lem:mylemm}\restatemarker
$1+1=2$
\end{restatable}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\mylemma*

\begin{proof}
We know that $2-1 = 1$, which shows the lemma.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could make the marker automatic with `\declaretheorem[postheadhook=\restatemarker]{lemma}`. In that case you should also remove the space after `\textup`

Comment: @mbert Yes, that's surely possible.